# Creating directory in uploads - wp_mkdir_p() or WP_Filesystem?

Tags: filesystem, wp-filesystem

I don't think I ever had practical need to create folders/files in WP before, but for a plugin I need cache (for resized images) folder in `wp-content/uploads`.

Which raises the question - do I really need to go through all the process with [`Filesystem API`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Filesystem_API) (including messily asking for FTP credentials when needed), or [`wp_mkdir_p()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mkdir_p) is good enough for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`wp-content/uploads/` should be writable for the server (otherwise it would be impossible to upload a file, no?). If you are going to create something under this directory, it is safe to use `wp_mkdir_p()`.

I would only use `WP_Filesystem` if there is a chance the server does not have permissions to write to the location, like in `wp-content/plugins/`, which does not have to be writable for the server (at least I think it doesn't have to be?).

Sidenote: [The File Permissions page of the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions) also talks about a `wp-content/cache/` directory. Would this be a "more standard" location for cache files?

Comment: I am not sure but I think `cache` is more about stuff like page caching plugins, while my case is more about alternate versions of images... The distinction between these folders seems semantic rather than technical, no?

Answer (score 6):

I'd try something simple, before messing around with an endless sea of possibilites/hosting setups:

```
$target = 'wherever';
wp_mkdir_p( $target );

if ( wp_mkdir_p( $target ) === TRUE )
{
    echo "Folder $target successfully created";
}
else
{
    new WP_Error; #... etc. Just tell where the user has to make a new folder with the name xy
    // or if you're kool, you use _doing_it_wrong(); ... ;-)
}
```

Comment: Btw: It's not tested and i got no clue whether to save the `wp_mkdir_p();` can be checked after execution or if the execution of the fn should inside the if statement... (never used it before and didn't even know about the function itself until now).

Comment: Related functionality is kind of back-end-ish... I'd like to minimize interactivity. Although message in plugin's setting is worth considering.

Comment: I wouldn't think too much about it. If the users sys can't do it with default values, try to tell them what to do. As i said: Possibilites are endless and imho you're better off with just telling what the result should be to continue as to try to trouble shoot this via code or support.

Answer (score 4):

Just a heads up on having your plugin create files/folders: my plugin did that as well, and I ran into a slew of issues with file permissions for different users.  Some are windows, some are unix, some are hosted, and some home grown. It was my #1 support email once I shared the plugin.

I have refactored my code to minimize the need to touch the file systems and the upload directory is the ONLY one I use now to avoid such issues.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that, that's why I bother to ask question. My current overview of the issue is that if `uploads` is locked down enough for WP to fail then there is no sense for plugin to try and do more. And if it's good enough for WP then it's good enough for plugin. Luckily I merely need cache directory anywhere and not something more complex and prone to errors.